# Faithful irreducible R-module implies simple

Tags: ring-theory, modules

I'm trying to solve this problem in Curtis's Representation Theory text.

The problem is: **If a ring $A$ with unity, satisfying the minimum condition, has a faithful irreducible $A$-module $M$, then $A$ is simple.**

In the section that has this problem, I just learned about Wedderburn theorem about simple ring $A$ being isomorphic to Hom$_D(M,M)$ for some division ring $D$.

The book's def for being $A$ being simple is that it satisfies the minimum condition and it has no proper nontrivial two sided ideal.

I assume $I \subseteq A$ is a nontrivial two sided ideal, then $IM$ is an $A$-submodule of $M$ so $M$ being irreducible implies $IM = 0$ or $IM = M$.    At this point, I can't deduct anything useful from this.

I also try to use the fact that $M \simeq A/J$ where $J$ is a left maximal ideal in $A$ but it doesn't get me anywhere.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If $IM=0$ then $A$ doesn't act faithfully on $M$.

Comment: @rschwieb no, I haven't, I only know about the decomposition of semi-simple ring and simple ring at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard equivalence of the many definitions that can be given to simple rings. The *Algebra* of Bourbaki has a very good presentation of it, so I will merely attempt here to provide a sketch of the proof.

Assume that ring $A$ is left artinian and admits a faithful simple left $A$-module $S$. By hypothesis we are given that:
$$\mathrm{Ann}_A(S)=\bigcap_{x \in S^{\times}}\mathrm{Ann}_A(x)=\{0_A\},$$
where I have taken the liberty to denote $S^{\times}=S \setminus \{0_S\}$.

By virtue of artinianity, any intersection of an arbitrary (nonempty) family of left ideals of $A$ can be expressed as the intersection of *only finitely many* of those ideals. In particular, in our case there exists a nonempty finite subset $H \subseteq S^{\times}$ such that $\displaystyle\bigcap_{x \in H}\mathrm{Ann}_A(x)=\{0_A\}$.

As $S$ is simple, it is generated by any element $x \in S^{\times}$; for any such nonzero element we consider the map:
$$\begin{align}
h_x \colon A &\to S\\
h_x(\lambda)&=\lambda x.
\end{align}$$
This map is clearly seen to be $A$-linear and surjective and we have $\mathrm{Ker} h_x=\mathrm{Ann}_A(x)$ by definition (hence $S \approx A/\mathrm{Ann}_A(x)$ as $A$-modules and therefore the annihilator in question is a maximal left ideal).

Consider now the map:
$$\begin{align}
f \colon A &\to S^H\\
f(\lambda)&=(\lambda x)_{x \in H},
\end{align}$$
the so-called direct product of $h_x$, $x \in H$ in *restricted* sense. It is clearly an $A$-module morphism and has the property that:
$$\mathrm{Ker}f=\bigcap_{x \in H}\mathrm{Ker}h_x=\{0_A\},$$
which means that it is injective. Thus, $A$ is isomorphic to an $A$-submodule of the isotypical module $S^H$. Since all submodules of a given isotypical module are isotypical of the same type, this means that $A$ itself is isotypical as an $A$-module.

In general, if $M$ is a semisimple left $A$-module then it remains semisimple when regarded as a (left, left) $(A, \mathrm{End}_{\operatorname{A-\mathbf{Mod}}}(M))$-bimodule, for any simple $A$-module $T$ the isotypical component $M_T$ being a *simple* $(A, \mathrm{End}_{\operatorname{A-\mathbf{Mod}}}(M))$-submodule of $M$. In particular, if $M$ is isotypical as a left $A$-module then it is simple as an $(A, \mathrm{End}_{\operatorname{A-\mathbf{Mod}}}(M))$-bimodule.

We apply this observation to our situation, by taking into account that:

- $\mathrm{End}_{\operatorname{A-\mathbf{Mod}}}(A) \approx A^{\circ}$ as rings and that:
- the $(A, \mathrm{End}_{\operatorname{A-\mathbf{Mod}}}(A))$-submodules of $A$ are ultimately the same thing as the $(A, A)$-submodules of $A$ with respect to the (left, right) $(A, A)$-bimodule structure on $A$,

we gather that $A$ is bilaterally simple, since the $(A, A)$-submodules of $A$ are precisely its bilateral ideals. More explicitly, this means that the only bilateral ideals of $A$ are $\{0_A\}$ and $A$ itself, which together with the assumption of left artinianity recovers your textbook definition of simplicity for $A$.

---

**Simpler variant of the above proof**

Let us resume the above train of thought at the point where we established the embedding $f \colon A \to S^H$. I will ask you for the continuation of this proof to familiarise yourself with the very simple result which essentially states the following:

> if $T$ is a family of simple $A$-modules indexed by a certain set $I$, $M$ is a left $A$-module isomorphic to the direct sum $\displaystyle\bigoplus_{i \in I}T_i$ and $N \leqslant_A M$ is an $A$-submodule of $M$, there exists a subset $J \subseteq I$ such that:

$$N \approx \bigoplus_{i \in J}T_i \quad (\operatorname{A-\mathbf{Mod}}).$$

In plain speech, this means that any submodule of a *semisimple* module is itself semisimple and has the particular consequence that any submodule of an *isotypical* (i.e. a semisimple in which all the simple summands are isomorphic to each other) module is itself isotypical. It is an elementary result in the theory of semisimplicity, with easy to understand proofs that you can find in either Bourbaki or Serge Lang's algebra treatise.

Once you have accepted and assimilated this result, we can return to our setting and deduce from the above embedding the existence of an *isomorphism* $g \in \mathrm{Hom}_{\operatorname{A-\mathbf{Mod}}}\left(A, S^F\right)$, where $F \subseteq H$.

To make explicit my notation conventions in the subsequent portion, for arbitrary $A$-module $M$ and additive subgroups $G \leqslant A$, $T \leqslant M$ I will write $G.T=\langle GT \rangle$ for the "subgroup product", which is the additive subgroup generated by the subset product $GT=\{\lambda t\}_{\substack{\lambda \in G\\t \in T}}$. As you will be able to gather, the whole purpose of the "." syntax is to avoid confusion between subgroup products and subset products, both being equally important objects in the study of linear algebra.

Consider now an arbitrary *nonzero* bilateral ideal $\{0_A\} \neq I \leqslant_{\mathrm{b}} A$. Since $I$ is in particular a left ideal we have that $I.S \leqslant_A S$ is a submodule of $S$, therefore either $I.S=\{0_S\}$ or $I.S=S$ by virtue of simplicity. The first case would entail the contradiction $\{0_A\} \subset I \subseteq \mathrm{Ann}_A(S)=\{0_A\}$, so we are led to the conclusion that $I.S=S$. As a remark, the same conclusion could have been more generally reached for any nonzero *left* ideal.

Let us now exploit that $I$ is also a *right* ideal, by noticing that $I.A=\langle IA \rangle=\langle I \rangle=I$, on the one hand. On the other hand, since $g$ is $A$-linear we also have: $$g[I]=g[I.A]=I.g[A]=I.\left(S^F\right)=\left(I.S\right)^F=S^F=g[A]$$
and on the grounds of $g$ being injective we infer that $I=A$. This means that there is no other nonzero bilateral ideal than the improper one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I don't think he ever talked about isotypical module and the fact about isotypical component that you mentioned in the text.  I wonder if there is an easier way since this is a bit much for an exercise in the text.  anyways, thank you so much.

Comment: @Khoa ta Several things I would like to say: 1) I am glad if the answer was of any help to you; 2) (of course you are in no way at fault in this regard, but) I disagree with this practice some textbooks exhibit of relegating important structural results to the ''exercises'' area; 3) I understand what your standing is in the matter so may I edit my answer to include a somewhat easier, less involved proof. Take a look at it and see if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience and for clarification your reasoning for me, I really appreciate it.  I think I'm familiar with the result that you boxed but the terminology you used in the original post is different than what I learn so it seems unfamiliar to me at first.  So I learned that a semisimple ring can be written as direct sum of simple components, where each component is the sum of minimal left ideals that are all isomorphic to each other, and I believe you called this isotypical. Beside that, everything makes sense now, thank you again!

Comment: @Khoa ta Once again, I am glad to know that I was of use in helping you understand things better. This could easily turn into a whole lecture on semisimplicity, but in order to keep things short let me say that the natural definition of a semisimple ring is that of it being semisimple when regarded as a left module over itself. On grounds of the general theory of semisimple modules this definition easily entails the fact that a semisimple ring is decomposable as the direct sum of finitely many bilateral ideals and therefore isomorphic to a direct product of finitely many simple rings.

Comment: @Khoa ta *(cont.)* A simple ring can be defined in several equivalent ways, one of them being that it is *isotypical* as a left module over itself (the other ones being the conjunction between left artinian and admitting a faithful simple module respectively the conjunction between left artinian and bilaterally simple, as per your exercise). At any rate, I would like to make the pedagogical point that a thorough study of the general structure theory of semisimple modules should precede the introduction of simple&semisimple rings in any textbook that seeks to be easy to follow.

Comment: Thank you for all the good info, I'm trying to learn Rep Theory by myself so I'm reading the textbook Rep Theory by Curtis.  I thought I only need to know some group theory, linear algebra and some module theory to comprehend the text, but apparently, I need to know a bit more about ring theory as well.